# converting white space into line break

Tags: css

Is it possible to add a line break on each white space using CSS?

For example, if I have string `"Format It"` I would like to display it like

```
Format
It
```

using CSS.

Comment: not possible with css.

Comment: you can't with only css, but you can with javascript like `$('p').text().replace(" ","<br/>");`

Comment: @r3wt You probably meant `.replace(/\s/g,"<br/>");` : using a string as first argument makes only one replacement

Comment: @dystroy i didnt, but thanks for teaching me something.

Comment: @r3wt well, you ---teached--- taught me "133t" (yes, I'm *that* old)

Comment: @dystroy you probably meant *taught* ;-)

Answer (score 18):

You can use the `word-spacing` property. It defines the space between the words. If you set it to the size of the container, it will force a line break...

Since it doesn't accept percentual values, you can use relative values like `vw`.

```
div {
    word-spacing: 100vw;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ApL3h/

Answer (score 6):

A solution would be to make it not wide enough, the standard `white-space` handling will make the lines wrap :

```
p {
  width:1px;
}
```

[demonstration](http://jsbin.com/suxuke/1/edit)

But it really depends on your use case and specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

div { white-space: break-spaces; }