# How can we break two words into separate line?

Tags: html, css

I have a word 'Mon 24'. 
What is the best approach to break it into different line as in

`Mon
24`

through css?

I have tried using `word-break: break-all` but no luck.
https://codepen.io/bbk_khadka/pen/zbVLEp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510027/converting-white-space-into-line-break

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[Can CSS force a line break after each word in an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212909/can-css-force-a-line-break-after-each-word-in-an-element)".  Take a look at that link-- I think it might contain what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the maximum width to be 3 characters wide

```
.text {
  max-width: 3ch;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJjpKV

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason this does not work for span tags?

Comment: probably because spans default to display:inline. If you apply display:block it will work https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aMgRWN

Comment: @BibekKhadka add `display:block` to your span tag.

Answer (score 2):

`word-break: break-all` will not support all browsers to wrap down. My suggestion to use `max-width` and `table-caption` to wrap.

```css
.text {
    display: block;
    max-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class='text'>Mon 24<div>
```

```css
.text {
    display: table-caption;
}

Let the element behave like a <caption> element.
```

```html
<div class='text'>Mon 24<div>
```